# Make table cell height change gradually

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am aware how to make a table cell disappear but it happens in the blink of an eye. I want the table cell's height to gradually get smaller when a function is called. I am very new to Javascript and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to animate anything, it is easiest to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). jQuery is a library of Javascript functions that makes life a lot easier. The function you need is .animate(). To start, add this line of code in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Set up your table and give the row that you want to get taller the id `heightchange` (it can be anything. I'm using this in this example). Then, add this to the head section of your HTML document (below the line you added above), add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function expandTableRow() {
        $('#heightchange').animate({
            height: '200px'
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then, create your button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:expandTableRow();">Click here to expand</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a live example that we can see? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Safari. But still, I would prefer an answer in javascript

Comment: This is still Javascript. jQuery is an expansion of Javascript that makes a lot of functions a lot simpler. Their tagline is "Write less, do more". You can check out the [getting started wiki page](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you imagine only one table cell changing in height. But maybe you just want to achieve the appearing of a table cell content?

This could be done with a css3 transition:
`transition: color 1000ms linear;`

==> [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/5NBvz/3/)